# Codeigniter's session table structure

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, primary-key

I would like to understand why CI's session  table structure has these three primary keys: *`session_id`*, *`ip_address`* and *`user_agent`*.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
        session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
        ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
        user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
        last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        user_data text NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (session_id, ip_address, user_agent),
        KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

Please explain the most you can, also, I would like to hear suggestions to improve this structure. Why are `ip_address` and `user_agent` primary_keys, not just indexes? What's the difference?

Another info, this table adds a row to every user's access to the system, so, it is very bloated.

Edit: Another question that come to mind. Why would I care about user agent match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea here is that each session will be unique. How does it identify a session? By the three values in the primary key: `session_id`, `ip_address`, and `user_agent`.

If you think about it, this makes sense:

1. If the `session_id` changes, then (obviously) you're dealing with a different (new) session.
2. If the `ip_addess` changes, then somebody's logging in from a different PC - this will be a new session.
3. If the `user_agent` value changes, then somebody's using a different browser - again, this will be a new session.

So imagine that only the `session_id` is the primary key: changing either `ip_address` or `user_agent` would simply update the existing row for the `session_id`. If that were the case, knowing only the `session_id` would make it possible for me to continue the same session on another PC or with a different browser, which might be a security concern.

You also wrote "this table adds a row to every user's access to the system, so, it is very bloated". I'm not sure if you mean every time user A accesses the system it adds a row (which is false on my application, I just tested it) or if you mean it adds a row for each user accessing the system (which is true, and the way it's supposed to work - each user using the system has a session). Maybe you could clarify that last comment.

Comment: Yes, every different user has a row.. Also, they have another rows which are old session data, which is garbage collected, right?

Comment: So, if I decide that in MY application I'm not matching IP_ADDRESS, should I remove it from the PK?

Comment: Because many users have dynamic IP ADDRESS that change often, when your modem resyncs, reboots, etc. That's why I usually DO NOT MATCH session against IP_ADDRESSes. That's how many big websites do, right? Facebook, google..

Comment: Re: different rows for different users - yes, they are garbage collected eventually. I don't know how often. Re: matching IP addresses -it probably wouldn't hurt anything to remove it from the primary key, although I would be surprised if your user's IP addresses changed often enough to present a problem (during a single session at your website? how long do they spend logged in?)

Comment: The point is that I intend to enable a session that lasts forever.. So, forever is enough time to have a IP change.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then you're going to need to look into the garbage collection in CI so that your users are not logged out when their session is deleted.

Comment: So, `'sess_expiration' = the number of SECONDS you want the session to last. by default sessions last 7200 seconds (two hours).  Set to zero for no expiration.` is not right because setting it to zero, makes the GC remove all the sessions? That's kinda buggy, no?

Comment: It is taken care, they set expiration to 2 years if you set it to zero.

Answer (score 1):

"primary keys" is an oxymoron. A table cannot ever have more than one "primary key". And as written up, there is only one primary key - it's just a **COMPOSITE** key that contains 3 separate fields.

That means

```
(42, 127.0.0.1, "Chrome")
(42, 127.0.0.1, "Firefox")
```

are two entirely different sessions as far as CI is concerned, even though the IP and session ID numbers are duplicates. The 3-way tuple is unique, but individual components can be duplicated.

Comment: I have added an edit questioning User Agents. Thanks for your answer.